# Difference Convex Programming using Convex-Concave Procedure (CCCP)

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose I have this optimization problem:

$ min f(X) - g(X), s.t. f(X)-g(X)\le 0, |X|\ge 0$

where $X$ is a square, symmetric, SPD matrix $\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, $f(X)=\sum_{a\in S} a^TXa$, and $g(X) =\sum_{b\in D} b^TXb$. $S$ and $D$ are two disjoint set in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

We know $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both convex and twice differentiable ( I believe..). So this is a DCP (difference convex programming) which can be solved by Convex-Concave Procedure (CCCP). Based on the CCCP, one can iteratively solve $X_{t+1}$ by:

$min f(X) - g(X_t) - \nabla g(X_t)^T(X-X_t)$ subject to the same constraints.

Let me substitute $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ into the cost function:

$ J =\sum_{a\in S}a^TXa - \sum_{b\in D}b^TX_tb - tr(\sum_{b\in D}bb^T(M-M_t))$

So using the sub-gradient method:

$ G = \partial J/\partial X = \sum_{a\in S}aa^T-\sum_{b\in D}bb^T$

We can update $M=M-\alpha G$. However, this problem seems not converge.

I found the linearised cost function is equal to the initial difference of convex problem, is this means CCCP cannot be used in this case?

$ J =\sum_{a\in S}a^TXa - \sum_{b\in D}b^TX_tb - tr(\sum_{b\in D}bb^T(M-M_t))\\
\ \  =  \sum_{a\in S}a^TXa - \sum_{b\in D}b^TX_tb - tr(\sum_{b\in D}bb^TM)+tr(\sum_{b\in D}bb^TM_t)\\
\ \ = \sum_{a\in S}a^TXa - \sum_{b\in D}b^TX_tb -\sum_{b\in D}b^TXb + \sum_{b\in D}b^TX_tb\\
\ \ = f(X)-g(X)$

**Extended question:**

What will happen if I change my cost function to:

$J=\sum_{a\in S}exp(-a^TXa)-\sum_{b\in D}exp(-b^TXb)$

and subject to only $|X|\ge 0$. This one can be linearised to :

$J=\sum_{a \in S}exp(-a^TXa)-\sum_{b \in D}exp(-b^TX_tb)-tr([\sum_{b\in D}exp(-b^TX_tb)bb^T]^T(M-M_t)) $

The important thing is, the set $S$ and $D$ are changing (hopefully reducing size) during the optimization. So I'm using sub-gradient method to compute the gradient.

Comment: Your functions $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are linear in $X$.

Comment: But linear is convex isn't it?

Comment: Yes trivially, but why talk about difference of convex and linearizations when it is linear? Your problem is $\min \text{tr} (CX)$ subject to $\text{tr} (CX) \leq 0$ and $|X|\geq 0$ (whatever you mean with that). It is either 0 (if $C$ is psd) or unbounded.

Comment: Great answer, I got it! Could you please see my extended question, which I use a non-linear version?

Comment: So now your question basically says that you have tried to implement an algorithm, and it did not work? Impossible for anyone to answer why. Why sub-gradients, you have simple exponentials?